# Varnish cache headers to browser

Tags: varnish

Is it possible for varnish to send the "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" cache control response to browser, while varnish caches the response.

Scenario is like this.

- Backend sends cache control :Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
- Varnish should cache the response.
- Browser should not cache the contents so in response from varnish to -browser should show "cache control :Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"

I have tried using Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate in set beresp.http.Cache-Control, but this causes varnish not to cache the responses.

Given below is the vcl_backend_response used.

```
    sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (bereq.url == "/") {

    unset beresp.http.expires;
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    set beresp.ttl = 3600s;
    set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=0";
    if (beresp.status >= 400 && beresp.status <= 599) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `varnishlog -g request` when you're doing a request? It could be that you're sending in cookies or an authorization header which will cause `vcl_recv` to return `pass`, which means "don't cache".

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use vcl_deliver in your .vcl config file:

```
sub vcl_deliver {
   set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private";
   set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
}
```